# Sequence define by a recurrence relation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can we simplify this expression?

$$A_n=\frac{\prod\limits^n_{k=0}((2k+1)^4+\dfrac{1}{4})}{\prod\limits^{n+1}_{k=1}((2k)^4+\dfrac{1}{4})}$$

Comment: Try to write this down for some easy numbers (like from 3 to 6) and see what happens.

Comment: @Dominique explain your idea

Comment: Note that $k^4+\frac14=\left(k^2-k+\frac12\right)\left(k^2+k+\frac12\right).$ Use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24A_n%3D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cprod%5Climits%5En_%7Bk%3D0%7D((2k%2B1)%5E4%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7D)%7D%7B%5Cprod%5Climits%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D_%7Bk%3D1%7D((2k)%5E4%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7D)%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: @Invisible thank you very much sir and merci beaucoup

Comment: De rien, Deval! (=: